# Splash screen in Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, user-interface, splash-screen

How can I display a splash screen using C or C++ in Windows?  What libraries or Windows components would be applicable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to create a window with the createwindowex function and use the style (*dwStyle*) WS_POPUP.
You can read about CreateWindowEx [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632680(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 4):

A splash screen is typically just a modeless dialog with a static picture control covering its surface, or even just a normal window that loads and blits a bitmap to its client area. [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/splasher.aspx) has an example of the latter sort. It uses MFC, but that's a thin enough wrapper over the Win32 API that rewriting it to use Win32 directly should be fairly simple.

Comment: Getting the threading right is the hard part.  Looks like that was done properly in the linked project.